# Three machines are in use certain number of minutes each hour. What is the probability that at least one will be in use at a given moment of the day?

Tags: probability

> Assume we have three machines, label them as $A$, $B$, and $C$. Machine $A$ is used $30$ minutes per hour, machine $B$ $10$ minutes per hour, and machine $C$ $5$ minutes per hour (these are average values). Additionally, machines $B$ and $C$ are *never used at the same time*.
>
> If machine $A$ is independent from machines $B$ and $C$, what is the probability that at a given moment of the day, at least one machine (no matter which one) will be in use?

I have no idea how to model this. <s>My first thought was the Poisson distribution, but that's a discrete one and won't be of much help, I think</s> (the more I think about this, the less sense it makes to use a certain "distribution").

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try treating $B$ and $C$ as a single machine $D$

Comment: I edited the question to elaborate that we're looking for the probability of at least one being in use at a given moment of the **entire day**, not just an hour.

Comment: @MarkBennet: So, treating $B$ and $C$ as a single machine $D$, I'd simply have that the probability I'm asked for equals <the probability that $A$ is in use> $+$ <the probability that $D$ is in use> $-$ <the probability that both $A$ and $D$ are in use>. Is this correct?

Comment: Your method would work.  So too would $1 -$ proportion of time A **not** in use $\times$ proportion of time D **not** in use

Comment: Note: treating $B$ and $C$ as a single machine does the same as treating the events "$B$ is on" and "$C$ is on" as mutually exclusive, which would be the mathematical model of the real situation.

Comment: If $B$ and $C$ are treated as a single machine $D$, then aren't they being used at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider machines B and C as a single machine D that is used $10+5$ minutes per hour.

So machine A is used $\frac12$ of the time and machine $D$ is used $\frac14$ of the time.

Therefore, you can simply add up the following probabilities:

- The probability of A active   and D active   is $\frac12\cdot\frac14=\frac18$
- The probability of A active   and D inactive is $\frac12\cdot(1-\frac14)=\frac38$
- The probability of A inactive and D active   is $(1-\frac12)\cdot\frac14=\frac18$

Hence the probability that at least one machine is used is $\frac18+\frac38+\frac18=\frac58$

Comment: I wrote this answer after the comment by @Mark Bennet was made, but I did not see that comment.

Comment: "The probability of A active and D active is $\frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{4} = \frac{3}{8}$." I believe it should be $\frac{1}{8}$, and the final result $\frac{5}{8}$, but thanks a lot for answering and confirming the answer I came to after getting @MarkBennet's hint.

Comment: @d125q: Oooops... Thanks :)

Comment: I have no problem with other people having the same idea!